# U-BOOT Displaying splash screen on BeagleBone Black and LCD

Tags: u-boot

I'm trying to display a splash screen on a BeagleBone Black with the 
Chipsee 7" LCD expansion board. I'm wondering how difficult this is with 
the latest U-Boot 2016 ? I can see that there are some framebuffer drivers 
available (am335x-fb.c) but it's not clear how to 
configure U-Boot to use them. Could somebody give some hints or an 
example, please?

Comment: Checkout: https://boundarydevices.com/display-configuration-u-boot/ for some hints. If you are using an older U-Boot (< 2015) you can get some help from: http://e2e.ti.com/support/processors/f/791/p/217383/1602144#1602144